# input/output error while copying PNG files from linux server to desktop using scp in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, png, scp, winscp

I am trying to copy some png files from linux server onto my local desktop running windows 7. I am trying to copy the files with cygwin using the scp command. I do not get any syntax errors but all my files are copied with input/output error. 
The size of images on my local after copying matches the size on the server but the image appears to be empty or cannot be viewed. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Most of the suggestions on this issue are about using WinSCP but I have tried that and it results in the following message:

```
*General Failure(server should provide error description).
Error Code:4
Error Messsage from server:Failure*
```

I have tried pscp as well which results in `error while reading: failure`.

Please let me know if you know how to get around this issue.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Also include WinSCP log file and tell us what is it "input/output error".